# Confusion about prices on Amadeus Flight API

Tags: amadeus

I will use “Flight Offers Search" API of Amadeus and ready to move to prod. But i was a bit confused about the prices i received for sample requests. i expected to see prices close to airline website prices. however, I see that the prices are incredibly high in comparison.

at first i thought it was related to using the test API of Amadeus, but the situation did not change after i bought the production API.

for example, for the non-stop and one-way flight TK7202 from SAW to VAN flight dated December 14, 2024, I receive fare information **from Amadeus API as 7420,800 TRY.** However, **on the official website** of the airline company that owns the flight, there is **1205.00 TRY** fare information for the same flight. This means that Amadeus is almost 6 times higher for the same flight.

Answer (score 0):

The Amadeus for Developers Self-Service APIs will have the prices coming directly from the GDS and not any negotiated fares. That means that an airline website could offer a lower price to give incentive to travellers to book from there. Same approach can be followed by some online travel agencies that have access to negotiated fares. You can check [here](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/faq/?h=negotiat#why-are-the-prices-returned-more-expensive-than-on-other-websites) for more details.